# Tensorflow NaN loss during training

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have made a neural network which is basically a copy of a tutorial on the tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers). The only difference is that my neural network is a 3D conv net and not a 2D conv net. I had many errors regarding my data and I'm not sure whether this one also is an error from my data.

```
NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```

Before that error shows up tensorflow prints out probabilities that only have the value 1:

```
probabilities = [[1.][1.][1.] ... [1.]]
```

It ends with a small error notification:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Model diverged with loss = NaN.
```

I have made a github gist for you to take a look at the code and the error message. https://gist.github.com/hjkhjk1999/df11c401578f4da83214fba16c210e45

I'm also providing a dropbox link to the data I'm using. My data has given me so many errors that someone ought to take a look at it.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iwnvnu57yktdf8f/Preprocessed%20Data.rar?dl=0